# How to Run an API Calls in Parallel (Node.js)

Tags: arrays, node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I am trying to run some API calls in parallel, but am having problems since I am trying to call a function again before the API data has been returned.

I am thinking that I could possibly use the `new` command in Node, but am not sure how to structure it into this scheme. I am trying to avoid recursion, as I already have a recursive version working and it is slow.

Currently I am trying to this code on the server.

```
loopThroughArray(req, res) { 
  for(let i=0; i<req.map.length; i++) {
    stack[i] = (callback) => {
      let data = getApi(req, res, req.map[i], callback)
    }
  }

  async.parallel(stack, (result) => {
      res.json(result)
  })
}
```

....

```
function getApi(req, res, num, cb) {
  request({
    url: 'https://example.com/api/' + num
  },
  (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
      // Log error
    } else {
      let i = {
        name: JSON.parse(body)['name'],
        age: '100'
      }
      console.log(body) // Returns empty value array.length > 1 (req.map[i])
      cb(i)
    }
  })
```

Is there a way to spawn new instances of the function each time it's called and accumulate the results to send back as one result to the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of calling Web APIs (each with different parameters), using the Async library, we start by creating an array of N function variables.

```
const async = require('async');
const request = require('request');

//Set whatever request options you like, see: https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback
var requestArray = [
    {url: 'https://httpbin.org/get'},
    {url: 'https://httpbin.org/ip'}
];

let getApi = function (opt, callback) {
    request(opt, (err, response, body) => {
        callback(err, JSON.parse(body));
    });
};

const functionArray = requestArray.map((opt) => { 
    return (callback) => getApi(opt, callback); 
});

async.parallel(
    functionArray, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error: ', err);
        } else {
            console.log('Results: ', results.length, results);
        }
});
```

You can easily switch the Url and Query values to match whatever you need. I'm using HttpBin here, since it's good for illustrative purposes.

Comment: That should be fine, you'd just form the Url for each request based on the arguments passed. I'll update my answer!

Comment: I've modified the answer so the requests are now in an array, you can set Url, Query string, headers for each one. In this case there are only two, however, you can create or map it as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for this example! It's going to take me a minute to wrap my head around it. I'm running into problems calling the same API endpoint consecutively the JSON parsing fails...

Comment: You don't have to include the JSON.parse, you can just pass the body if you like, e.g. callback(err, body). This will pass a string rather than an object.

Comment: I see, so perhaps I should parse the body in the API controller?

Comment: You could indeed!

Comment: Hm, I'm still having trouble understanding why the body would return an empty string when `array.length > 1`.